# Pass a socket io connection to an ajax success function

Tags: jquery, ajax, socket.io

I am trying to access a socket io connection within an ajax success function.

```
    // Create socket connection
    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:81/');

    // Ajax request gets auth token
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:8000/foo',
        xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: true
        },
        success: function (result, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            socket.on('connect', function () {
                $('#rows').html(result);
                socket.emit('message', result);
            });
        }
    });
```

How do I do this? If I declare the connection within the success function it works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are showing looks confused.  The `connect` event may have already happened before the ajax call completes so you would completely miss it.

If there is a legit reason to not want to insert the ajax results into the DOM until the socket has connected, then you can do it like this:

```
// Ajax request gets auth token
// start ajax call, save promise
var p = $.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:8000/foo',
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    }
});

// Create socket connection
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:81/');
socket.on('connect', function () {
    // when both socket is connected and ajax call is done, insert results into DOM
    p.then(function(results) {
        $('#rows').html(result);
        socket.emit(result);
    });
});
```

Comment: @Brian - I've updated my answer to match your edit.  Next time, please tell people who've replied with a targeted comment that you edited your question to address issues they pointed out.  Otherwise, we never know you made an edit.